# Background image not showing on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I am making a website in which there is a background image which fills the entire screen. It works fine on desktop browsers, but does not render on an iPad. Here is the css:

```
body { 
    background: url('pics/net.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The html is really just a panel that appears above the image. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/G7rEb/ The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Check for path issues